# Решение проблемы IIS и CORS

Tags: iis, cors, iis-7

В общем, есть сайт, который обращается через JS к файлам, которые смаплены в IIS, как виртуальный каталог.

Браузер выкидывает ошибку CORS...

Как это можно обойти в IIS?

Нашел вот такой Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

, который разместил в папке (эта папка является корнем сайта) с тестовым файлом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема осталась...

Answer (score -1):

Подсунул другой конфиг и все заработало:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```